# Rails new app fails due to permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rubygems

I've searched for some time now but can't solve the problem. I'm on a relatively new computer (osx), only created one rails app on it so far. Until now everything went well. I'm now trying to create a new app using

```
rails new appname
```

This is what the terminal shows me:

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.0.4) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.7.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.13) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.13) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.2) 
Installing tilt (1.4.1) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/build_info/tilt-1.4.1.info
An error occurred while installing tilt (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install tilt -v '1.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I enter

```
gem install tilt -v '1.4.1'
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

While searching I've found people with similar looking errors but I couldn't find anything solving my specific problem.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 2.3.13.

I really stuck and hope someone knows how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I noticed, when I run the rails new app command, the terminal asks me

```
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system:
```

It has never done this before. Is it possible that I kind of have changed something on the system?

**Update2:** After using 2+ days on this, as far as I can say, the solution was to completely reinstall the latest versions of ruby and rails.

Comment: are you using [rvm](https://rvm.io)?

Comment: Also note that with rails, it's a good idea to put your gems into `Gemfile` and let `bundle` (or `sudo bundle`) do the installation. You might also want to check out `rvm`.

Comment: Yes I'm using rvm but I don't how to use it in a way to solve this problem. Wouldn't "sudo bundle" be used after "rails new" succeeded? It seems like the whole initial setup gets aborted way too early? Thanks so far!

Comment: woah there, don't `sudo bundle`

Comment: LinusAn -- can you confirm you are using ruby 2.0? Also, ruby 2.0 and rails 2.3 don't mix. If you are starting a new rails app, please use 3.2.13 or 4.0.0.beta1

Comment: Yes, rvm is set to '2.0.0' (if thats how you say that). What do you mean by they don't mix? I am using 3.2.13, sorry if I didnt't specify it.

Answer (score 3):

try `sudo`
or create your app in a directory which is accessible to you

Comment: I tried to create the app on the desktop but it didn't work. What directory should I use then?

Comment: Doesn't matter what folder you go under as long as the user running has permissions to create. My preference is i put web stuff under /var/www/foldername

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo gem install tilt -v '1.4.1'`

Comment: When I run this, there are coming a couple of other similar errors for different gems. Do I have to run this command for all the gems which chan't be installed every time I wan't to create a new app?

Comment: @LinusAn I have not found a work around. But I usually only get this error on windows

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm on a mac in the first place, but there doesn't seem to be a protective hand this time ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If the sudo "gem install tilt -v '1.4.1'" doesn't work.
Then most likeley, the group "others" don't have correct permissions in your Ruby innstall.
Make sure, you give correct permissions for group=others or users running the command in your:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

Comment: When I run gem install tilt -v '1.4.1' in the path I get the following error again: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/tilt-1.4.1.gem

Comment: Can you list directory permissions on "your Ruby install dir/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8"

Comment: How do I do that? Thank you very much for your help!